# The Stupid Error: Undefined $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've googled like mad and can't figure out why this isn't working and I'm getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error. I have my JS script first, and put my script at the bottom but totally just lost. any help here?

```html
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

.day {
background-color:#000;

}

.sunset {
background-color:red;
}

.night {
background-color:green;

}

</style>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”lib/jquery.min.js”></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="one" style="padding:4px;border:1px #000;">Schedule Box</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Change background depending on user’s time
function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 19)
// If time is 7PM or later apply night theme to ‘body’
$('body').addClass('night');
else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
// If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
$('body').addClass('sunset');
else
// Else use ‘day’ theme
$('body').addClass('day');
}
window.onload = applyclass;

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For whatever reason, your attempt to load jQuery didn't work. Check the "Network" tab in your browser developer tools to investigate.

Comment: If that's a direct copy/paste of your code, you've got some non-standard quotes (`”` instead of `"`) in your reference to the jquery lib

Comment: I don't get how so many people end with those quotes. Just in Case, Microsoft Word isn't a good code editor.

Comment: I ended up copying from a website and pasting it and the paste must have messed it up. I only use Notepad. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You used bad `""` change this:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”lib/jquery.min.js”></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```